# ordenar campos en fila quitando nulos - SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

estoy intentando realizar una pequeña consulta la cual simplemente es ver la cantidad de transacciones que ha hecho un cliente dividiéndolas por moneda (HNL y USD), el query que tengo es el siguiente

```
SELECT 
CASE WHEN bp.Currency='USD' THEN COUNT(bp.BPTypeCode) END AS [Cantidad Transacciones Dolares],
CASE WHEN bp.Currency='HNL' THEN COUNT(bp.BPTypeCode) END AS [Cantidad Transacciones Lempiras]

FROM dbo.Transacciones bp 

WHERE  bpr.ClientId='11326749' 
   AND bp.ValueDate BETWEEN '2021-12-01' AND '2021-12-31'
   AND bp.BPStatusId=10


GROUP BY bp.Currency
```

El query funciona, sin embargo no me arroja el resultado que deseo, me arroja el siguiente resultado

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y quiero que todo sea en una sola fila, asi:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ya que se pondrán mas clientes, si alguien me ayuda para ver como hacer eso

Comment: si vas a tener mas clientes, para empezar, agrupa por clientes. Ahi estas agrupando por monedas, y por lo tanto, va a salir una moneda distinta por linea...

Answer (score 3):

En este caso lo que tienes que generar no es un count, si no una suma y dentro de cada suma validas el tipo de transacción para determinar si sumas un item a tu acumulado o no.

Ejemplo.-

```
CASE WHEN bp.Currency='USD' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
```

Al ejecutar esa validación, cada registro generara la validación y te regresara un valor (1,0) dependiendo de si cumple la condición, y al aplicar la suma te arrojara el acumulado por condición.

```
Sin Suma
[Cantidad Transacciones Dolares]    [Cantidad Transacciones Lempiras]
1                                   0
0                                   1
1                                   0

Con Suma
[Cantidad Transacciones Dolares]    [Cantidad Transacciones Lempiras]
2                                   1
```

Aquí te dejo como deberías aplicarlo con tu ejemplo  y deberá funcionar.

```
SELECT 
    SUM(CASE WHEN bp.Currency='USD' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS [Cantidad Transacciones Dolares],
    SUM(CASE WHEN bp.Currency='HNL' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS [Cantidad Transacciones Lempiras]
FROM dbo.Transacciones bp 
WHERE  bpr.ClientId='11326749' 
   AND bp.ValueDate BETWEEN '2021-12-01' AND '2021-12-31'
   AND bp.BPStatusId=10
GROUP BY bp.Currency
```

Comment: También podría hacerse: `COUNT(CASE WHEN bp.Currency='USD' THEN 1 ELSE NULL END)`